# In objective-C (ios) ,Has anybody used singleton instance?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, singleton

In memory perspective of singleton instance how can we delete singleton instance created.since its being placed into autorelease pool?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you saying you WANT to release a singleton, or your singleton IS being released?

Comment: @ashley:Yeah ii want to release singleton instance

Comment: Can you explain to us why you want to do that? The whole point of a singleton is that it's a single instance you create once. If you're releasing and then creating another instance later, it's not a singleton.

Comment: Go with the @synchronized posted in this page. That will give you effective output of singleton object.

Comment: @Kuldeep In iOS 4.0 or greater, you should move to dispatch_once... it's thread safe and much quicker

Comment: @AshleyMills Doesn't differ much in account of safety and speed of execution, its a deal for one cycle execution that's all.

Answer (score 3):

Singleton instance shouldn't be placed in autorelease pool. Singleton instance should be created once (usually when first referenced) and deleted when the application terminates (I mean automatically by iOS). This is why singleton is usually assigned to a static variable.

You should increase the reference counter (retain) the singleton instance when assigning to that static variable. At that point even if you add it to an autorelease pool it won't be deleted as it is already retained somewhere else.

To delete that singleton instance you would simply need to release the current object assigned to the static variable (e.g. release) and assign nil or create a new singleton. If the same instance has been added to an autorelease pool it won't be deleted immediately, only after that autorelease pool has been deleted itself. But it shouldn't change much in your application as the singleton is already nil or recreated as a new instance, thus any further calls will retrieve the new instance.

Again, I don't see any reason why you would add a singleton to autorelease pool. Please share a snippet of code if this doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

See this link

http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/

Apple briefly explained it here. Under'Creating a Singleton Instance' topic

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html

Comment: Thank you..ill go through them

Answer (score 1):

There's some debate on how to create a singleton. I use the following pattern:

```
+ (MYSingletonClass *) sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static MYSingletonClass * __sharedInstance = nil;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        __sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });

    return __sharedInstance;
}
```

On clarification by the OP, it turns out this doesn't answer the question, but I thought I'd share anyway :)

See the [this post](http://bjhomer.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/synchronized-vs-dispatchonce.html) comparing @synchronized v dispatch_once

Comment: If you're the person who voted me down, please leave a comment so I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Singletons are helpful because you do **NOT** release them until your app is closed. So your data are always available.

If you need to free memory I suggest you find a different way to menage data...

Answer (score 0):

```
static id sharedInstance=nil;

+(id)sharedInstance 
{
    @synchronized(self) 
    {
        if(!sharedInstance)
       {
           NSLog(@"Allocated");
           sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
       }
   }
   return sharedInstance;
}
//standard way to declare singleton object
```

Comment: In iOS 4.0 or greater, you should move to dispatch_once... it's thread safe and much quicker

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add a "clear" method to you singleton object if you need to clear its content...